# How to Bind Collection of Objects from UI to Backend using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring, user-interface, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How to return List of Objects to Backend Service? For E.g. there are list of customer getting displayed in UI, out of which only those customers which users selects (checks in checkbox) should be returned to the backend (Controller class). But i am not able to returned the selected object back.

My code:

```
public class CustomerType {
    private String customerName;
    private String customerMsg;
    private Boolean selected;
    // setter 
    // getter
}
```

​

```
public class Customers {
    private ArrayList<CustomerType> customerType;
    // setter 
    // getter
}
```

​

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
public String index(ModelMap modelMap) {
    ArrayList<CustomerType> customerType = new ArrayList<>();
    customerType.add(new CustomerType("1", "c1", null));
    customerType.add(new CustomerType("2", "c2", null));
    customerType.add(new CustomerType("3", "c3", null));
    Customers customers = new Customers();
    customers.setCustomerTypes(customerType);
    modelMap.put("customers", customers);
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/save")
public String save(@ModelAttribute Customers customers, BindingResult errors, Model model)  {
    ...
    ...
    return "hello";
}
```

​

```
========== index.html ==========
...
<form id = "form" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" role="form"
    th:action="@{/save}" method="post" th:object="${customers}">
    <div class="checkbox"  th:each="customerType : ${customers.customerType}" >
        <input type="checkbox" id="custType" name="custType"
            th:text="${customerType.customerName}" th:value="${customerType.customerMsg}" th:checked="${customerType.selected}"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am able to display lists of Customers on UI e.g there are three customer c1, c2, c3 out of which if user selects c1 and c3 so after clicking on submit button those should get mapped to @ModelAttribute Customers Object in save method and that **object should contain list of two Objects c1 and c3, but instead of getting 2 Objects I am receiving Null.**

I am not able to get where i am going wrong.

Comment: Could you share your Thymeleaf template?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
 <div class="container" id="customersDiv">
  <h3>Customer Type</h3>
  <form id = "form" <!-- form section same as above -->
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sending your form back to controller, be sure that transmited data reflect desired object structure. You have to provide checkboxes that correspond the `checked` field of the `CustomerType` objects and additional hidden inputs which correspond others fields of mentioned class.

Please update your form to looks like:

```
<form id = "form" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" role="form" th:action="@{/save}" method="post" th:object="${customers}">
    <div class="checkbox"  th:each="customerType, iterator : ${customers.customerType}" >
        <input type="hidden" th:field=*{customerType[__${iterator.index}__].customerName} />
        <input type="hidden" th:field=*{customerType[__${iterator.index}__].customerMsg} />
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{customerType[__${iterator.index}__].selected}" th:text="${customerType.customerName}" ></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

With this you'll receive the `Customers` object containing list of all passed `CustomerType` objects, with `selected` fields evaluated to **true** for checked records.

Comment: I am getting the following error even after having setters and getters even tried to use name property for respecitve input type e.g name="customerName" but still its giving same error 
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'customerType[0]' of bean class [com.dto.Customers]: Bean property 'customerType[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: Does your `Customers` class have methods `public ArrayList<CustomerType> getCustomerType()` and `public void setCustomerType(ArrayList<CustomerType> customerType)`?

Comment: yes it have both methods : public ArrayList<CustomerType> getCustomerTypes() and public void setCustomerTypes(ArrayList<CustomerType> customerType)

Comment: There has to be something wrong with the signatures, otherwise it would work. Look carefully at your setter. Inside method marked with `@GetMapping` you have the line `customers.setCustomerTypes(customerType);`. The setter has plural ending _setCustomerType**s**_. If field is called _customerType_ then setter should be called _setCustomerType_. This could cause the problem.

Comment: :Thanks i changes the setter and getter names, its working now thanks.  can you give more information regarding "*{customerType[__${iterator.index}__].selected}" what exactly * and __ are used for ?

Comment: The relevant info you can find in the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html). The `*{}` selector with `th:field` attribute picks properties from form-backing bean (provided as `th:object`) - this is covered in [section 6.2](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs). The `__${...}__` syntax is a preprocessing expression, which is an inner expression that is evaluated before actually evaluating the whole expression (mentioned in [section 6.6](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields)).

Answer (score 1):

The `name` of the `input` fields in the form should match the property name in the `CustomerType` class i.e they should be `customerName` and `customerMsg` for the Spring to be able to create and populate the corresponding `CustomerType` object.

Comment: Even after changing name  to customerName i am still getting as null ,
 not able to populate those objects in backend 
<input type="checkbox" id="custType" name="customerName"
            th:text="${customerType.customerName}" th:value="${customerType.customerMsg}" th:checked="${customerType.selected}"></input>

Comment: Try to change the `@ModelAttribute` to directly bind to `ArrayList<CustomerType> customerType`

Comment: @MohamedSanalla Even tried changing that still not able to populate the objects