# How to get checked as well as unchecked values of check boxes in thymeleaf + Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

If I have three checkboxes E.g. 
-- c1
-- c2
-- c3
Out of which user selects c1 and c3 so **how will I capture value for all checkboxes** whether they are checked or unchecked i.e **(true, false, true) or (1,0,1)**  from thymeleaf to backend controller class ?
I am able to capture values for  checked ones but not for unchecked ones, can someone let me know how can I obtain checked as well as unchecked values ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I answered to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47241440/5684265) of yours. Check it out as my answer concers this question as well.

Comment: just provide a value for all of them and they should be available on the server. So on the `change` event for checkbox, you just check `is(":checked")` if yes then set the value to 1 else to 0. You can use `jQuery` to make your life simpler while dealing with DOM